# How to configure remote IP address audit logging for VPN clients on a Cisco 2801

Tags: cisco, logging, cisco-vpn

We have a Cisco 2801 that also acts as a VPN Server for Cisco VPN Client.
We would like to configure IP address logging so that each time a user connects using VPN we would like to log his IP Address.

So far there were only 3 of us. However as time passes by more and more employees are required to connect to the office using VPN and I don't want to use `sh crypto isakmp sa` to verify the IP address for each new VPN connection.

---

For example: When someone form the group `stuff` logs in I would like that and his IP address to be logged to the syslog.

In the example bellow a user with source IP address `92.XX.XX.157` has connected to the VPN server. The only thing I am reciving on that router is:

```
Feb 12 11:53:14: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Virtual-Access5, changed state to up
```

But there is no way to know who loged in untill i connect to the router and issue `sh crypto isakmp sa`

```
Router#sh crypto isakmp sa
IPv4 Crypto ISAKMP SA
dst             src             state          conn-id slot status
81.XX.XX.XX    92.XX.XX.157    QM_IDLE           1111    0 ACTIVE
Router#
Router#sh crypto session
Crypto session current status

Interface: Virtual-Access5
Profile: sdm-ike-profile-1
Group: stuff
Assigned address: 192.168.5.151
Session status: UP-ACTIVE
Peer: 92.XX.XX.157 port 38238
  IKE SA: local 81.XX.XX.XX/4500 remote 92.XX.XX.157/38238 Active
  IPSEC FLOW: permit ip 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 host 192.168.5.151
        Active SAs: 2, origin: crypto map
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`crypto logging session`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/security/command/reference/convert/sec_a1_cr_book/sec_c4.html#wp1061803) command is about the best you're going to get. It was introduced in IOS 12.3(4)T. This will cause tunnel up/down events to be logged in the form:

```
%CRYPTO-5-SESSION_STATUS: Crypto tunnel is UP  .  Peer 10.0.0.1:500       Id: 10.0.0.1
%CRYPTO-5-SESSION_STATUS: Crypto tunnel is DOWN.  Peer 10.0.0.1:500       Id: 10.0.0.1
```

There's not much detail in that logging. If you're using the "EasyVPN" functionality then the [`crypto logging ezvpn`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/ios-easy-vpn/prod_white_paper0900aecd803fc77b.html) will give you even more detail.

You should definitely be logging at your AAA server in addition to logging at the router itself.

Comment: That helped and that was all I need.  A simple command to track the remote peer. I really don't know why noone answered this before..